# How can I locate hamburger icon for desktop view using protractor?

Tags: protractor

I am a newbie to a protractor. Want to locate hamburger icon for desktop view. But don't know how. Am attaching IMG for reference please help me out

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a specific unique way of locating it, I'd recommend using by className.
Try this:

```
var hamburgerIcon = element.all(by.className('gs-hamburger')).last();
```

If that doesn't work, you can try more specifically with a css selector:

```
var hamburgerIcon = element.all(by.css('.p-2.ng-star-inserted span .gs-hamburger')).last();
```

The `.last();` is because for desktop view, you need the second element.

Then use the variable and click it:

```
hamburgerIcon.click();
```

Comment: I believe you need the second element. I missed it originally also but the poster states they are looking for 'Desktop view' image and the first img src is appended with '-mobile'.

Comment: @DublinDev I missed that. Will edit it in a few seconds. Thanks.

Comment: @Joaquin Casco Thanku very much...the first one worked for me..thanks for the response again

Answer (score 1):

Update: I misread the original question-

```
let hamburgerImg = element(by.xpath('//img[@src="assets/media/img/logos/gs-hamburger.png"]'));
hamburgerImg.click();
```

There is good information on [the protractor site](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) regarding locators and how to use them. Always remember that Protractor is a wrapper for WebdriverJS so when thinking about fundamental interactions like this it is useful to also search for question regarding `selenium-webdriver` or `webdriverJS`.

Any questions let me know.